# Identifying error and finding the value of a variable in Red Hat Linux Apache Server script

Tags: linux, apache, redhat

I am a Red Hat noob.  My Apache server is not working.  When I open up the error logs, the only thing I see is "/usr/binall/SSFEXISTS: line 52: not a tty: No such file or directory"

I did some research and found that SSFEXISTS is a script that is used by a very old piece of software our company uses.  I am trying to figure out why it's outputting an error.

1. What part of the script could that error be coming from?
2. How can I find the value of the variable $CPSICWDATE.  Where is it defined?  Is there a way I could have it echo the value?

Thanks for your help!

```
# Date created............: 8/24/95
# Last modification.......: 11-8-01 - added -PC option
#                           Now returns FOUND/NOT FOUND/DONT KNOW (if old cw)
# Purpose.................: Returns "FOUND" if the file exists "NOT FOUND"
#                           if it doesn't.

RET=0

TTY=`tty`
OLDSTTY=`stty -g 2>/dev/null`
trap 'stty $OLDSTTY <$TTY >/dev/null 2>&1;exit $RET' 0 2 3

CheckForPCFile()
{
  if [ $CPSICWDATE -gt 990947 ]
  then

    # loop until received Special End of Doc Code
   stty icrnl -clocal ixon -ixoff -ixany -opost -echo -isig icanon eof 
________________________________________
   <$TTY 2>/dev/null
    awk 'BEGIN {printf("%c%c%s%c%c", 235,188,"'"$1"'",188,235);}' >$TTY
   while [ "$x" != FILEEXISTSYES ] && [ "$x" != FILEEXISTSNO ]
  do
    read x
  done
stty $OLDSTTY <$TTY 2>/dev/null
if [ "$x" = FILEEXISTSYES ] 
 then 
  echo FOUND
 else
  echo "NOT FOUND"
  RET=1
fi 
 else
echo "DONT KNOW"
RET=2
  fi
}

case "$1" in
  -[Pp][Cc]) CheckForPCFile "$2" ;;
      *) if [ -f "$1" ]
          then
            echo FOUND 
           else
            echo "NOT FOUND "
            RET=3
         fi ;;
esac
exit $RET   **NOTE:  This is line 52**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The error is due to this line:

`trap 'stty $OLDSTTY <$TTY >/dev/null 2>&1;exit $RET' 0 2 3`

It sets up a `stty` command to be run when the script exits, which it does on line 52.

2. You can print out the value for the error log with:

`echo >&2 "The value of CPSICWDATE is $CPSICWDATE."`

The script is outputting an error because it was not meant to be run from a web server. It expects to be run in a terminal connected to what appears to be some kind of legacy system, e.g. through `ssh`, `telnet` or dialup. It's not fatal by itself.